# Find min and max date-time stamps for distinct locations/serial numbers that may appear more than once

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime, cursor, common-table-expression

Hello out there and happy Halloween! I am using SQL SERVER 2008 R2 on a WIN7 machine; I am having some issue trying to parse some data and would be stoked if anyone may be able to help me with this issue.

I have attached an example of a data set I am trying to refine a bit. In this set I have 6 fields (this is only a subset of a much larger set) that range from Name, Model, Location, Type, Serial Number and Date-Time. In this subset, the name and model fields remain constant but the location, type, serial number and date fields change.

What I am trying to achieve is this; for every location I would like to know the min and max "date time" associated with every serial number install along with the corresponding fields associated with each tuple i.e. for every serial number I'd like to know the min and max time along with the location/serial number/model/name for that specific serial number instance.

This seemed straight forward but when I realized that the serial number may be removed and appear again for the same location my query failed. I first attempted to simply grab the min and max time for every distinct serial number/location combination but that quickly faltered when I discovered that these serial numbers did not appear only once for every location. In the end I'd just like to know how long each serial number was installed for.

I appreciate any help, thank in advance!

[image]

-Stelio K

Comment: Please show your attempts.

Comment: I can't, due to the nature of my work I could get into trouble just for posting this. I understand if you do not want to help though. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a sub query. The sub query on the inner join will limit your result set to the record which contains the max DateTime for each serial number, as stated "for every serial number I'd like to know the min and max time along with the location/serial number/model/name for that specific serial number instance"

```
select 
  t.name,
  t.model,
  t.Location,
  t.Type,
  t.[Serial Number],
  t2.DT as MaxDT,
  NULL as MinDT
from yourTable t
inner join
(select [serial number], max(DateTime) as DT 
from yourTable 
group by [serial number]) t2 on t2.[serial number] = t.[serial number] and t.DateTime = t2.DT
UNION ALL
select
  t.name,
  t.model,
  t.Location,
  t.Type,
  t.[Serial Number],
  NULL as MaxDT,
  t2.DT as MinDT
from yourTable t
inner join
(select [serial number], min(DateTime) as DT 
from yourTable 
group by [serial number]) t2 on t2.[serial number] = t.[serial number] and t.DateTime = t2.DT
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately this will only grab max times; if I also do this for mins and join those times I will still only have the first and last time these serial number appeared. Sometimes they will re-appear after removal so I am trying to find a way to get the min and max times for every appearance of a serial number in a given location.

Comment: Ah i missed that part. You can do this with a union all or partition by

Comment: I am sure I can I am just not getting it but thank you!

Comment: i added a union to this @StelioK not the best way but it'll work too

Comment: This is basically what I've done, I can get the max and min time for every serial number but this doesn't take care of those intermediate appearances , when it is removed and installed again.

Comment: Then you don't want the min and max for the SN, you want it for the entire tuple...

Comment: I do need the min and max for every SN but for every appearance of that SN. I guess you could call it the domain for every appearance of the SN; that's what is really throwing a wrench in it for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation functions over a partition, maybe this works for you? See the [OVER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx) clause documenation for more info.

```
select a.NAME
     , a.MODEL
     , a.LOCATION
     , a.[TYPE]
     , a.SERIAL_NUMBER
     , a.DATE_TIME
     , Min(a.DATE_TIME) over (partition by a.LOCATION, a.SERIAL_NUMBER) MIN_DATE_TIME
     , Max(a.DATE_TIME) over (partition by a.LOCATION, a.SERIAL_NUMBER) MAX_DATE_TIME
from (values
    (N'COMPANY', N'EI-MEX', N'12A', 'PAS-B', 2027, Convert(datetimeoffset(0), N'2014-10-03 04:04:21'))
  , (N'COMPANY', N'EI-MEX', N'12A', 'PAS-B', 2027, Convert(datetimeoffset(0), N'2014-10-03 04:18:21'))
  , (N'COMPANY', N'EI-MEX', N'16A', 'PAS-B', 2029, Convert(datetimeoffset(0), N'2014-10-02 03:57:25'))
  , (N'COMPANY', N'EI-MEX', N'16A', 'PAS-B', 2029, Convert(datetimeoffset(0), N'2014-10-02 04:53:35'))
  , (N'COMPANY', N'EI-MEX', N'19A', 'PAS-T', 499, Convert(datetimeoffset(0), N'2014-03-20 22:33:37'))
  , (N'COMPANY', N'EI-MEX', N'19A', 'PAS-T', 499, Convert(datetimeoffset(0), N'2014-03-21 04:48:36'))
  , (N'COMPANY', N'EI-MEX', N'19A', 'PAS-T', 499, Convert(datetimeoffset(0), N'2014-03-21 05:57:25'))
  , (N'COMPANY', N'EI-MEX', N'19A', 'PAS-T', 499, Convert(datetimeoffset(0), N'2014-03-21 06:01:22'))
  , (N'COMPANY', N'EI-MEX', N'19A', 'PAS-T', 499, Convert(datetimeoffset(0), N'2014-03-21 08:39:46'))
  , (N'COMPANY', N'EI-MEX', N'19A', 'PAS-T', 499, Convert(datetimeoffset(0), N'2014-03-21 09:21:49'))
  , (N'COMPANY', N'EI-MEX', N'19F', 'PAS-T', 2362, Convert(datetimeoffset(0), N'2014-03-11 14:01:42'))
  , (N'COMPANY', N'EI-MEX', N'19F', 'PAS-T', 2362, Convert(datetimeoffset(0), N'2014-03-11 14:14:35'))
) as a (NAME, MODEL, LOCATION, [TYPE], SERIAL_NUMBER, DATE_TIME);
```

Comment: This is very close, and very elegant. The issue with this is that for a given location, if the serial number appears, is removed and appears again I will not have those intermediate min and max values only the first/last instances. Thanks!

Comment: @StelioK Then remove the distinct clause at the top and import the `DATE_TIME` field. I have updated my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is interested :) I figured it out. Feel free to critique it, I'd appreciate it:

```
SELECT * INTO #TEMP
FROM MYTABLE;

WITH ROW AS 
(
    SELECT *
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Name, model, location, [DATE TIME]) AS RN 
    FROM #temp
)
    SELECT DISTINCT R1.Name, R1.model, R1.Location, R1.TYPE
            , r1.[SERIAL NUMBER], r1.[DATE TIME]
            INTO  #THEDELTAS
                FROM ROW R1
                    JOIN ROW R2
                    ON (    R1.RN = R2.RN - 1
                                AND R1.NAME = R2.NAME
                                AND R1.model = R2.model
                                AND R1.LOCATION = R2.LOCATION
                                AND R1.[SERIAL NUMBER] <> R2.[SERIAL NUMBER]                            
                        )
                        order by Name, model, location, [DATE TIME];
WITH ROW AS 
(
    SELECT *
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Name, model, location, [DATE TIME]) AS RN 
    FROM #temp
)
    SELECT DISTINCT R1.Name, R1.model, R1.Location, R1.TYPE
            , r1.[SERIAL NUMBER], r1.[DATE TIME]
            INTO  #THEDELTAS2
                FROM ROW R1
                    JOIN ROW R2
                    ON (    R1.RN = R2.RN + 1
                                AND R1.NAME = R2.NAME
                                AND R1.model = R2.model
                                AND R1.LOCATION = R2.LOCATION
                                AND R1.[SERIAL NUMBER] <> R2.[SERIAL NUMBER]                            
                        )
                        order by Name, model, location, [DATE TIME]                 

--GET MIN/MAX TIMES
SELECT * INTO #TEMP2 
FROM 
( 
SELECT  DISTINCT A.Name, A.model, A.Location, A.TYPE
        , A.[SERIAL NUMBER]
        , MIN(A.[DATE TIME]) [DATE TIME]                
                FROM #temp A
    GROUP BY Name, model, location, TYPE, [SERIAL NUMBER]
UNION       
SELECT  DISTINCT A.Name, A.model, A.Location, A.TYPE
        , A.[SERIAL NUMBER]
        , MAX(A.[DATE TIME]) [DATE TIME]                
                FROM #temp A
    GROUP BY Name, model, location, TYPE, [SERIAL NUMBER]
    ) AS T
ORDER BY Name, model, location, TYPE, [DATE TIME]       

SELECT * 
FROM (
SELECT * FROM #TEMP2
UNION 
SELECT * FROM #THEDELTAS 
) AS T  
UNION 
SELECT * FROM #THEDELTAS2
ORDER BY Name, model, location, TYPE, [DATE TIME]
```